# Adding column of numbers in linux vi editor

Tags: linux, vi

I have used following commands to add columns in vi editor

visual block (ESC+Ctrl+V)
arrows use to select the column
x to delete value
again ctrl+v
Shift+I (go to the top and insert)
Type the value
Esc+enter

I want to repeatedly add 1 and 2 as in the snapshot attached. Can you please assist me with this. thanks

[image]

Comment: ESC+CTRL+V to enter visual selection, select the column 1,2,1,2, press YY to yank in the default register, then move to the desired position and, always in command mode, press p or P (depending if you want the column pasted before or after the cursor)

Comment: You do not use `ESC+CTRL+V` to enter visual mode.  Your mind set is wrong.  You just do `CTRL+V`; otherwise you are confusing normal mode and insert mode.

Comment: @WilliamPursell visual selection != visual mode, but probably I should've used Block Selection or Visual Block or whatever is now called in Vi(m)

Comment: vimscript is a bit verbose, but you could try: `:'<,'>!perl -pe 'substr($_,20,1)=($v++\%2+1)'`. (Tweak the 20 to fit the column in which you want to insert the text)

Comment: Hi William, Thank you for your suggestion. I can not run perl as it is not installed. As I'm using hpc I can not install it locally as well.

Comment: Thanks BigMike for your suggestion. I tried this. But when I paste the yanked column the first column also get disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

- Position the cursor at the location where you want to start typing 1.
- Start a macro `qa`.
- Type what you want to type. `i1<esc>` `jh` `i2<esc>` `jh`. So that you end up 2 lines below, so that it is something repeatable.
- Stop the macro `q`
- Execute the macro dazilion times `200@a`
- Watch